# textit use with tex4ht in mathjax mode

Tags: macros, tex4ht, mathjax

I am trying to compile Latex code generated by Maple. The Latex generated contains things like `\textit{\_C1}` which works OK in pdf, but when compiled to HTML using tex4ht, in mathjax mode, it does not work, since mathjax does not support nesting inside this macro ([reference](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/243))

> MathJax does not process macros in text-mode, since it only handles
> math-mode macros. So within \text{} or \hbox{} or other text-mode
> material embedded within math mode, no macros are performed. That is a
> feature not a bug. :-)

I tried to use `\renewcommand` to redefine `\textit{\_C1}` to `{\it \_C1}` which works in HTML/mathjax, but not able to do it. The command is not changing in HTML, it still shows as `\textit{\_C1}`

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ifdefined\HCode 
\renewcommand{\textit}[1]{{\it#1}}
\fi 

\begin{document}

\[
y(t) = \textit{\_C1}
\]

  
\[
y (t) = {\it \_C1}
\]
\end{document}
```

Compiled to pdf using lualatex, both give same output

[image]

But compiled to html

```
  make4ht -ulm default foo3.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

[image]

The HTML generated is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta  charset="utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo3.css" /> 
<meta name="src" content="foo3.tex" /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", inlineMath: [ ["\\\(","\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, processEnvironments: true, packages: ['base', 'color', 'ams'] }, loader: { load: ['[tex]/color', '[tex]/ams'] } }; </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" async="async" id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js"></script>  
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 12--><p class="noindent" >\[ y(t) = \textit{\_C1} \]
</p><!--l. 17--><p class="indent" >   \[ y (t) ={\it \_C1} \] </p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

How to correct my `\renewcommand` so that `\textit{#}` gets changed to `{\it #}` automatically to make mathjax happy? (I can't change Maple Latex code generation code) Or is there a better way to fix this other than using `\renewcommand`? May be need to add new configuration in tex4ht for this macro for mathjax?

Using TL 2020

Comment: Newer versions of MathJax include an extension to support macros within \text{}, including \it, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/textmacros.html.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger thanks. I use mathjax 3.*, will try to add this textmacro to my configutation and see what I get.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger thanks again, got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your LaTeX generator produce `\textit` in math mode? I would say that it is an error. It should use `\mathit` instead. `\it` shouldn't be used at all, it is a deprecated command. Anyway, as your document is rendered by MathJax and it explicitly says that it doesn't support math content inside `\textit`, so there is nothing we could do.

This works in both `pdflatex` and MathJax:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[
y(t) = \mathit{\_C1}
\]

  
\[
y (t) = {\it \_C1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Maple just generates Latex for an expression. i.e. given a math expression, it generates only the latex for this expression. Then I copy this latex to my latex document and put it inside `\[ \]`. So I would say most of the latex generated is meant to be used in math mode, but Mapleitself only generate the latex for the expression, and does not generate `\[ ... \]` or `$...$` with it.

Comment: But how can I change `\textit{\_C1}` automatically to `\mathit{\_C1}` ? When I tried `\renewcommand{\textit}{\mathit}` it did not work. it seems `\renewcommand` has no effect in  mathjax mode? I'll try to ask Maplesoft to change `\textit` to `\mathit` but for now, I wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Michal, got it working ok using the new macro from mathjax. I did not know about it. Thanks for the info about mathit. I do not think Maple will change their code to do that which would be the better solution otherwise.

Comment: @Nasser yes, a macro definition for MathJax is probably only solution.